# Make PHP + MySQL applications into software for Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, windows

So I have built a lot of php+mysql+javascript applications and deployed on the server side. Users can access my applications on the server, via a browser on the client computer.

However, is there any easy way to migrate a whole php+mysql+javascript application into Windows just like a software.

Users can download an installation package that includes the whole WAMP environment and the php+mysql+javascript application. After the user starts the program, a window with the native IE rendering engine would automatically open up http://localhost:1234. The window would be bare minimum with just borders - users doen't have to know it's a browser.

**Any existing software or framework helps achieve this?**

Seen from the users, it's NO different from any other software. Can it be made as clean and cool as a native software created with C++ and .NET? I know the applications are essentially still just web pages, but would there be any other problems that would make this a bad practice?

Comment: A gentle reminder : make sure you check the MySQL licensing terms before considering this, you might need a commercial license to pull this off... See [Commercial License for OEMs, ISVs and VARs](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/). PostgreSQL (for one, and there are others out there) doesn't have this limitation :p.

Comment: @wimvds, Thanks! So Apache and PHP are fine to be included in a commercial product?

Comment: Actually, I don't know, I've never redistributed Apache/PHP in commercial apps, so you should check their respective licenses (and it's probably best to get some legal advice). But from the looks of it Apache shouldn't pose a problem as long as you stick by the rules (attribution & including the license) [Frequent Questions about Apache Licensing](http://www.apache.org/foundation/licence-FAQ.html#WhatDoesItMEAN)

Comment: Ok, PHP should be fine too since it's a modified BSD license, see [PHP Licensing](http://php.net/license/index.php), and [PHP Distribution Guidelines](http://www.php.net/license/distrib-guidelines-code.php) :p.

Comment: @wimvds, Thanks a lot for the help. That's what I think too. Will probably give it some serious reading off the licenses, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [InnoSetup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to do this. Just download the binaries of the packages you wish to include and add your PHP source, run these from InnoSetup, making sure you unpack your PHP code and configure Apache correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Yuo could use a standalone webserver and php module like

http://www.zachsaw.co.cc/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger

and put this with your root directory in a single installation package (e.g. with NSIS).

Also have a look at http://wapache.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know how active the project is anymore, but you could look at http://gtk.php.net/

Comment: As far as I know, GTK compiles to binary code. However with what I want, my application remains a website.